# Finding a file to modify in a trac plugin (trac-git)

Tags: python, windows, compiler-errors, trac

I recently installed Trac on windows for the first time. After setting everything up I got this error when trying to browse the source in a GIT repository:

```
Trac detected an internal error:
WindowsError: (5, 'Access is denied')
```

It doesn't look like many people have come across this as the only ticketed bug for this hasn't had many responses, but there was a guy who suggested that I modify the file PyGIT.py. Looking further into my own exception I find this:

```
    return gen.next()
    yield historian

    if p:
        p[0].stdout.close()
        p[0].terminate()    # <-- This line highlighted as the problem
        p[0].wait()

def last_change(self, sha, path, historian=None):
    if historian is not None:
        return historian(path)
```

Now I am not sure but I read that this is something to do with how windows processes `p[0].terminate()` that causes the error and it was suggested that the exception was ignored by changing it to this:

```
try:
    p[0].terminate()
except WindowsError:
    pass
```

Weather or not this will work, I don't know. But what I'm wondering is - where on earth is this ***PyGIT.py*** file? All I have to go by is the path:

```
build/bdist.win32/egg/tracext/git/PyGIT.py
```

Am I right in thinking this isn't part of a compiled file or something? I installed the plugin that runs the code as a .egg

If anyone could give me a hand, all I want to do it see if I can modify the file!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed the plugin as a .egg file, then you probably don't have the source code.  The website where you downloaded the .egg file should also have a URL for their repository.  Simply check out a copy of the source code, make the suggested modification, and rebuild the .egg with `python setup.py bdist-egg`.

Comment: I did think the egg was compiled, but then how can the error page show me the code causing the problem and the line number?

Comment: @ing0- I'm not all that familiar with the particulars of the egg format, but I believe it retains enough information about the original code to display debug messages like that.  I don't know if you can extract the source code from the pre-compiled egg, though.

Comment: Ah ok. I've managed to build my new egg with the changes now, although my local machine has py2.7 and the server runs off 2.6 so I'm just sorting that out. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: The egg file is just a zip file with a renamed extension.  Although I'm not sure if you can just change the files and zip it back up.  I'll try it and report back.

Comment: Yep, works just fine.  Just make sure you restart trac after you make the change and it'll work fine.